# What software can be used for logical operations in spreadsheet data

Tags: linux, gui, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet(csv) file with 6 columns and 800 rows which I update daily with new data(file will be deleted and a new one is created). I want to do logical operations in those new data and also possibly with different queries .

example

```
query 1: 
find_rows= if(col1>100 and col2<500 or col5>70 or col6=="a")
query 2: 
find_rows= if(col2>100 or col2<6.99 and col6=="c")
.
.
etc
```

I know we can do this with some programmes like python but the problem is I have to write a full software with GUI to pass changing queries. Is there any software which can be used for logical operations of columns in spreadsheets.

Comment: Native, web-based, or indifferent? How would users enter the queries?

Comment: Move all your data to MS access or other database.  SQL queries, are exactly what you need.  select * from table where col1 >100 and col2<500 or col3="a";

Comment: @Gilles I want to use it for my personal use and I have no problems with any method